# Head bone not moving with parent hip bone

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

Not really sure how to word it, but I have an bone chain with a hip bone as the root and everything being a child of that.
When I move the hip it seems the tail of the head bone tries its best to stay in place, making it very difficult to translate the body as the head does some funky movements. Rotations work as expected, with the whole bone chain pivoting from the hip.

Very similar to [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41683/chest-bone-moves-unwantedly-with-the-hip-bone), but it seems like it's not applicable to me.

The only thing I noticed is that the head bone goes orange when translating the hip and a constraint icon pops up in the hierarchy but disappears as soon as I release.

Deleting the head bone makes the same unwanted movement occur on the neck, so it seems like it's trying its best to keep the tail of the bone chain at its original position pre-translation.

I followed [this video and playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jp_SqjB0468&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0f4c56CbvYi038zmCmoZ4CQ&index=3) to model and rig the character, and it doesn't seem like he has the same problem.

How can I fix this so that the whole body follows the translation of the hip bone?

This image from left to right shows idle with hip bone selected, hip translated to the character's left, and hip translated to the character's right and up.
[image: Idle, Translate Hip Right, Translate down - released - translated up]

[image]

Comment: to share a file use this site (read the instructions): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: thanks @moonboots added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have activated the *Auto-IK* option, it allows you to move a bone as if it had an *IK* constraint, so just deactivate it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked.